# jquery timeout after setting window.location

Tags: android, jquery, url, redirect

I am trying to detect if an app is installed on the android device. My app has registered an uri schema and if if go to "myapp://" in the browser, my app will be invoked.
Issue occurs if my app is not installed on the device. I would like to get the browser navigate to a different url if browsing to "myapp://" fails.

I thought this can be achieved by setting a timer in jquery.

For Example:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 50);
window.location = "myapp://";
```

This works fine on safari, as it just shows a pop up if it fails to load a url and in the background, this jquery will still be active and timer fires resulting in a redirect.

However in android, browser shows an error page that says it failed to load the url and timer never fires.

Is there a way to achieve this in such cases

Comment: If it's an error page, might it be because they protocol `myapp://` is unrecognized? Have you tried wrapping the latter `window.location` in a try/catch block?

Comment: i haven't tried that. i will see if that works

Comment: I don't know if android exposes developer tools as easily as Chrome does, but you may need to inspect the error to see what's really happening. Try this: `try { window.location = "myapp://"; } catch(e) { console.log(e); }` or whatever the available console.log equivalent is.

Comment: It's not throwing any exception, i go the page that says webpage not available